# Foundation 6 "t.getBoundingClientRect is not a function" error on browser resize

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using foundation 6 framework for my project and its working fine; but whenever I re-size browser window I get an error in console (attached a screenshor)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMbug.png)

```
foundation.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: t.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
at Object.o [as GetDimensions] (foundation.min.js:1)
at e.value (foundation.min.js:2)
at e.value (foundation.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js:8201)
at jQuery.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js:8275)
at MutationObserver.i (foundation.min.js:1)
```

Comment: I think I solved the problem, I had initialised foundation in jquery's ready function but as soon as I moved initialisation part under window.on("load" ,function(){...}); no error was thrown on browser resize

Comment: A codepen to reproduce here and more infos would have been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**!!!SOLVED**

I Had the same error.

Was using before the error:

```
$(document).foundation();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){...}
```

Just move foundation call inside the .ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).foundation();
});
```